# How do I write a complex sql or post sql query that will return all data relationships for an input?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, an account (A1) has two customers (C1, C2) that own the account. C1 is also an owner on a separate account (A2) with another customer (C3). C2 is also an owner on two other accounts (A3, A4), and another customer (C4) is a co-owner of A4.

I am looking for a (looping?) query that will identify all relationships (e.g. A2-4, C1-4) for the data input A1.

```
| Account | Customer |
|---------|----------|
| A1      | C1       |
| A1      | C2       |
| A2      | C1       |
| A2      | C3       |
| A3      | C2       |
| A4      | C2       |
| A4      | C4       |
| A5      | C5       |
| A6      | C6       |
```

Attempt:
select customer, account from Account.Customer
where account = A1;
for each(account)
[look up all customers that belong to account
for each (customer within that account)
[look up all accounts belonging to that customer]
]
break when there are no more new customers or accounts

Expected output

```
| Account | Customer |
|---------|----------|
| A1      | C1       |
| A1      | C2       |
| A2      | C1       |
| A2      | C3       |
| A3      | C2       |
| A4      | C2       |
| A4      | C4       |
```

Comment: Please read this and edit your question accordingly: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Pelease, share the information of each table that you want relate and, more important, the code that is generated an error and avoid make generic question.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting and vagueness. Still working on how to navigate this site and ask this type of question. Will provide any corrections as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a hierarchical query (`CONNECT BY` query). Since you are walking through a bi-partite graph, you must be careful not to generate certain rows more than once; I do that in the CONNECT BY clause, by choosing one condition or the other depending on the parity of the level.

You can make the starting account identifier (hard-coded as 'A1' below, in the `START WITH` clause) into a bind variable, if needed.

```
with
     inputs ( account, customer ) as (
       select 'A1', 'C1' from dual union all       
       select 'A1', 'C2' from dual union all       
       select 'A2', 'C1' from dual union all
       select 'A2', 'C3' from dual union all
       select 'A3', 'C2' from dual union all
       select 'A4', 'C2' from dual union all
       select 'A4', 'C4' from dual union all
       select 'A5', 'C5' from dual union all
       select 'A6', 'C6' from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select account, customer
from   inputs
connect by nocycle 
  mod(level, 2) = 1 and account  = prior account
  or
  mod(level, 2) = 0 and customer = prior customer
start with account = 'A1'     -- Or make it a bind variable, if needed
order by account, customer    -- If needed
;

ACCOUNT  CUSTOMER
-------- --------
A1       C1      
A1       C2      
A2       C1      
A2       C3      
A3       C2      
A4       C2      
A4       C4
```

Comment: Thanks. So this query did pull the data I needed, but the rows did repeat. However, when I modified the select statement to 'select distinct account, customer', only the distinct values of account + customer were returned.

Comment: @LikestoLearn -  Hmm... "distinct" is exactly what I was hoping to avoid, since it may affect performance. But if there is more than one way to get from (A1, C1) to (A4, C2), then (A4, C2) will indeed appear more than once anyway. If using "distinct" gave you the right answer and it didn't take too long, then everything seems OK.

Comment: Good point. I did not factor performance results into that response. And yes, unfortunately, there is more than one way to get (A1, C1) to (A4, C2) (probably wasn't exhibited in my limited dataset). Do you have a recommendation that could provide the "distinct" results without a performance impact?